# is it possible to get js variable to assignt c# string with using Jurrassic Library

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack, jurassic

I am getting js script from remote html with using HtmlAgilityPack as below;

....

```
string JsVars = _HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[contains(text(), 'blablaa')]").InnerText
```

JsVars returns as below;

```
var js_var1 = "blablaa";
var js_var2 = "hops";
```

is there anyway to get value of **js_var1** or **js_var2** values after Evulate jsVars with Jurassic?

```
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
var result = engine.Evaluate(_JsVars);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
var result = engine.Evaluate(_JsVars);
var var1 = engine.GetGlobalValue<string>("js_var1");
var var2 = engine.GetGlobalValue<string>("js_var2");
```

**[[.NET fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OPi1P8)]**

Reference : [Jurassic Documentation - Accessing and modifying global variables](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Accessing%20and%20modifying%20global%20variables&referringTitle=Documentation)